# Join group of words that are in a given list

Tags: python

My problem looks quite simple but I can't figure out a clean (and efficient) solution.

I have a list of tuples corresponding to common groups of words:

```
ngrams = [("data", "scientist"),
          ("machine", "learning"),
          ("c", "+"),
          ("+", "+"),
          ("c", "+", "+"),
          ("research", "and", "development"),
          ("research", "and")]
```

And a sentence:

```
"i am a data scientist . i do machine learning and c + + but no deep learning . i like research and development"
```

I would like to merge the common groups of words in a single token like that:

```
"i am a data_scientist . i do machine_learning and c_+_+ but no deep_learning . i like research_and_development"
```

I am sure there is an elegant way to do so but I haven't been able to find any..

If there were only 2-tuples, iterating on `zip(sentence, sentence[:1]` would do it, but I have up to 8-tuples in `ngrams` and this solution is not tractable!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you're attempting to do a variation of TF-IDF, checkout the sklearn package for Python http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer

Comment: `joined_ngrams = ['_'.join(t) for t in ngrams]`

Comment: That doesn't help. What I would like is transforming any given sentence in input to a sentence where groups of words appearing in `ngrams` are joined.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a list of replacement strings from your words in `ngrams`:

```
replace = [" ".join(x) for x in ngrams]
```

And then, for each element in that list, use `str.replace`:

```
for r in replace:
    sentence = sentence.replace(r, r.replace(" ", "_"))
```

There might be a more one-liner-y way to do it, but that seems relatively terse and easy to understand to me.

Answer (score 1):

While Haldean Brown's answer is simpler, I think this is a more structured approach:

```
ngrams = [("data", "scientist"),
          ("machine", "learning"),
          ("c", "+"),
          ("+", "+"),
          ("c", "+", "+"),
          ("research", "and", "development"),
          ("research", "and")]
sent = """
    i am a data scientist . i do machine learning and c + + but no deep
    learning . i like research and development
"""

ngrams.sort(key=lambda x: -len(x))
tokens = sent.split()

out_ngrams = []
i_token = 0
while i_token < len(tokens):
    for ngram in ngrams:
        if ngram == tuple(tokens[i_token : i_token + len(ngram)]):
            i_token += len(ngram)
            out_ngrams.append(ngram)
            break
    else:
        out_ngrams.append((tokens[i_token],))
        i_token += 1

print(' '.join('_'.join(ngram) for ngram in out_ngrams))
```

Output:

```
i am a data_scientist . i do machine_learning and c_+_+ but no deep learning . i like research_and_development
```

`ngrams` after sorting:

```
[('c', '+', '+'),
 ('research', 'and', 'development'),
 ('data', 'scientist'),
 ('machine', 'learning'),
 ('c', '+'),
 ('+', '+'),
 ('research', 'and')]
```

That's needed to try to apply `("c", "+", "+")` earlier than `("c", "+")` (or, in general, to try to apply a sequence earlier than its prefixes). Actually it's possible that non-greedy things like `[('c', '+'), ('+', 'a')]` are more desirable than `[('c', '+', '+'), ('a',)]`, but that's another story.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! I think I was stuck because I was trying to find a solution that would work in O(len(sentence)) by turning `ngrams` in a set. I still think it is possible but maybe less elegant!

Comment: I think it can be done in O(len(sentence)*len(longest_ngram)) by something like a dictionary that maps each shortest ngram in a family to its family (where family is a list of ngrams with a common prefix).

Answer (score 0):

```
s = ''
seq = ("c", "+", "+")
print(s.join(seq))
```

More in on join method:
Python docs

ttps://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join